# What is the exact solution for this equation?

Tags: algebraic-equations

I have been thinking about this equation:

$$x^2=2^x$$

I know there is two integer solutions: $x=2$ and $x=4$. But there also is a negative solution, that is approximately $x=-0.77$.

$$(-0.77)^2=0.5929$$
$$2^{(-0.77)}=0.5864...$$

Can we find this negative solution exactly?

Comment: Please put the equation in the title.

Comment: Do you know the Lambert W function? That's how you get your exact answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative solution to $x^2=2^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544703/negative-solution-to-x2-2x)

Comment: I believe he's looking for the exact solution, not an approximation.

Comment: quite right. i retracted that flag. I have a better dupe candidate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605114

Answer (score 1):

The solutions for the equation $x^{a}=a^{x}$ are given by $x=-\frac{a}{\log a}W\left(-\frac{\log a}{a}\right)$, where $W(\cdot)$ is the Lambert W-function, i.e., the inverse function of $f(W)=We^{W}$. Then we get $x_{1}=2,x_{2}=4, x_{3}\approx-0.7\bar{6}$.

**P.S:** To obtain the value $x_{3}$ we need to consider $x<0$, we get $x=-\frac{a}{\log a}W\left( \frac{\log a}{a}\right)$ in our case $a=2$ give $x_{3}=-\frac{2}{\log 2}W\left( \frac{\log 2}{2}\right)\approx -0.7\bar{6}$.

Comment: How do you get $x_3$ from $-\frac{2}{\log 2}W\left(-\frac{\log 2}{2}\right)$?  I thought $W(x)$ had two values, both negative, when $-e^{-1}<x<0$, and when you multiply these by a negative number such as $-\frac{2}{\log 2}$ you get positive results as in $2$ or $4$ here

Comment: @Henry You are right and thank you for the remark. I was reading your comment and I've been working on $x_{3}$ and I hope it's clear now. I corrected.

Comment: Indeed (+1).  The negative solution is then close to $-0.766664695962123\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is a solution of the equation $x^2 = 2^x$ if :
$$\dfrac{\ln|x|}{x} = \dfrac{\ln 2}{2}$$
from the graph of the function :
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\ln|x|}{x} - \dfrac{\ln 2}{2}$$
[image]

we deduce that there are only $3$ solutions $x = 2$, $x = 4$ and $x = -0.767$.